# SSRS Datasource connection to SQL Azure Data don't work from web based reports

Tags: reporting-services, azure-sql-database

I'm unable to generate a report from the web based interface (Report Manager). The same report in my Visual Studio project works perfectly.

The error which appear when trying to generate the report from the web is 
**"Cannot create a connection to data source"**

The log file error is the fallowing
**Cannot get edition information from catalog server.**

The report data is retreived from an SQL Azure database.

How come the report can work inside my Visual Studio project but no more once deployed?

I've tried both SQL Server 2012 and SQL Server 2008 on fresh machines and both gives the same result.

Thanks,

Comment: I am also having this issue but haven't worked out how to fix it, did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

After a half day of troubleshooting this issue, I discovered it was because the edition of SSRS I am using does not support Azure SQL Databases as a data source.

I am using 2008 Express Advanced Edition.  It appears Standard or above is required for this.

See this article for more information:
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqltact/2016/09/25/sql-ssrs-express-edition-cannot-connect-to-azure-sql-databases/